# How to generate header oauth token in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm doing load testing my REST API - to hit the API request header should contain a valid token. I'm dynamically generating my request body - the same way I would like to generate header token dynamically using JMeter - what is the best approach to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the resource which requires full authorization you need to provide so called ["Bearer Token"](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/) via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager), you need to add [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header  with the value of `Bearer ${followed by the dynamic token}`

[image]

The process of obtaining the token depends on [OAuth Grant Type](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/) used in your application, you need to figure out which authentication/authorization flow is being used and implement it in JMeter using HTTP Request samplers and suitable [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) for [correlating](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) the dynamic values.